# Observable pattern not notify in android

Tags: android, design-patterns, observable

i have implement a Observer/Observable pattern in android application, but when do the notify, receivers dont get the call.

This is my code:

The observer, is a class for call a rest service, if the call fails because the server is off, or other problem, i change the rest server ip, increase a int value from Observable and Observable must call my update override method, but dont do it:

```
    public class LoginApiCall extends ApiCallBase<Object> implements Observer {

        private String team;
        private String password;
        private String deviceId;

        private LoginIntents loginIntents;

        public LoginApiCall(Context context, String team, String password, String deviceId, ApiResponseListener listener) {
            super(context, listener);
            this.team = team;
            this.password = password;
            this.deviceId = deviceId;
            loginIntents = LoginIntents.getInstance();
            loginIntents.addObserver(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doWork() {

            LoginData login = new LoginData(team, password, deviceId);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String value = gson.toJson(login);

            try {
                ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));

                Api.post(context, "teamLogin", entity, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        apiSuccess(jsonObject);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable, JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        apiError(new ApiException());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable, String content) {
                        if (throwable.getCause() instanceof ConnectTimeoutException) {
                            System.out.println("Connection timeout !");
                        }
                        loginIntents.increaseIntents();
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        apiError(new ServerException());
                    }
                });
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
            execute();
        }
}
```

and this is the Observable, that when increase the intents attribute from 0 to 1, notify the observers and they should be do something:

```
public class LoginIntents extends Observable {

    private static volatile LoginIntents instance = null;
    private int intents = 0;

    private LoginIntents() {
    }

    public static LoginIntents getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LoginIntents();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public int getIntents() {
        return instance.intents;
    }

    public void increaseIntents() {
        instance.intents++;
        if (intents == 1) {
            notifyObservers();
            setChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Whats wrong? the notifyObservers method is called when i debug and the setChanged too, but dont enter in update method of Observer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't [setChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html#setChanged%28%29) be called before [notifyObservers()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers%28%29)?